# Christoffel symbol of the first kind

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, tensors, differential-geometry

Suppose that we are given a metric $$ds^2=-\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)c^2dt^2+\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d \theta^2+r^2\sin^2(\theta)d \phi^2.$$ Given the [Catalogs of Spacetimes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.4184.pdf) pdf we are given some mathematica code to calculate Christoffel symbols of the second kind $\Gamma_{\alpha\nu}^{\lambda}$, the Ricci and Riemann curvature tensors and the scalar curvature: $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ and $R_{\mu\nu}$ and $R$. Given all these computations, what I do not have to calculate is the Christoffel symbols of the first kind $\Gamma_{\lambda\alpha\nu}$ or the (1,3)-Riemann Curvature Tensor $R_{\mu\nu\alpha}^{\lambda}$. The code for the compitations I am fiven is given by: [image] and [image].

Is there any code I can use without having to refer to packages like xtensor or gr to calculate the christoffel symbols of the first kind in a non-coordinate basis? P.S the answer given in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151758/computing-christoffel-symbols-of-the-first-kind) post about the Christoffel symbols of the first kind was unhelpful for my situation.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defined a "mixed metric" in Xact/Xcoba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213696/defined-a-mixed-metric-in-xact-xcoba)